# rails each print last item with "True"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, haml

I have the following code in order to show some records of an user:

```
 = @kid.educations.each do |education|
   = education.studies_centre
   %br
   = education.city_and_country
   %br
   %small
     = education.academic_qualification
   %hr
   %br

= @kid.certificates.each do |certificate|
  = certificate.certificate
  %br
  = certificate.city_and_country
  %br
  %small
    = certificate.description
  %hr
  %br

= @kid.works.each do |work|
  = work.company
  %br
  = work.city_and_country
  %br
  %small
    = work.description
  %hr
  %br
```

but after every record, I get the word true, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

What can I do to solve this issues. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: evaluate code with `-`. Print it out with `=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
= @kid.educations.each do |education|
```

You should have:

```
- @kid.educations.each do |education|
```

etc.